# Fixing an iOS 11 crash using XCode 8

Tags: ios, xcode, uikit, xcode8, ios11

My app went viral (yay!) and it hard-crashes on startup for all users running iOS 11 (boo!). However, when I build and run it using XCode 9 beta (both 1 and 2), it works fine on both emulator and phone.

Since XCode 8 (which produces the broken build) can't debug an iOS 11 device, and XCode 9 can't replicate the crash, it seems there's no way to test potential fixes, except to put them on TestFlight. Even if I do that, there's no way to hook it up to the XCode 8 debugger. Is there an easier way to debug iOS 11 on XCode 8? Thanks!

(For the curious, the crash occurs in `UITableView._endCellAnimation` -- something about `__exceptionPreproces`s. Here's the snippet:

```
    let task = ItemSource.sharedSource.getRandomItems(10)
    task.continueWith(
        Executor.mainThread,
        continuation: {
            (task: Task<[Item]>) in
            let nouns: [Item] = task.result!
            self.controller.tableView.beginUpdates()
            var indexPaths = [IndexPath]()
            for noun in nouns {
                indexPaths.append(self.append(noun))
            }
            self.controller.tableView.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .none)
            self.controller.tableView.endUpdates() <-- Crashes here
        }
    )
```

Comment: iOS11 is _Beta_ at the moment; this crash may mislead you.

Comment: I know, but a lot of people install the beta and I've gotten lots of complaints about it. I *can* tell them that they shouldn't have installed a beta OS on their primary phone, but users don't like hearing that too much.

Comment: the _users_ are not supposed to install any _beta_ but they don't like to hear that indeed, so they will install _beta_ which is kinda okay but they forgot to accept the fact that the developers cannot fix a bug which is not devs' fault (and they don't have SDK to fix it). that is simple as 1-2-3.

Comment: Even though the crash is not my fault, I'd like to fix it if there's a way to do so. Hence the question.

Comment: I don't really get your concept of _fixing-something-which-is-outside-of-my-scope_, it is not your scope – you __cannot__ fix it.

Comment: If I could reproduce the crashes, I could try changing my code in various ways, and see if any of the changes make the crashes go away. Even though I didn't write UIKit and don't have a lot of visibility into what's going on under the hood, I can try a few other ways of adding cells to the table -- maybe one of those ways doesn't trigger the bug. That kind of trial-and-error is how I debug mission-critical problems that are happening at layers I don't have access to.

Comment: that leads back to my original question: why would you want to fix a code of yours which is not even broken? if you trigger a bug in iOS (or in a _beta_ version of iOS), just report it via radar.

Answer (score 5):

> Since XCode 8 (which produces the broken build) can't debug an iOS 11
>   device,

Copying DeviceSupport from Xcode9-beta to Xcode8 will solve this problem

Terminal command:

```
cp -a /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/11.0* /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/
```